# how to make an enum point to a class

Tags: python, class, enums

Suppose i have this enum for storing all the different Entity types

```
class Entities(Enum):
    TREE = auto()
    ROCK = auto()
    FLOWER = auto()
```

I would like to create a function that takes one of these (TREE, ROCK...) enums, and knows that an enum corresponds to a class i have.
eg.:

```
def myFunc(EntityType):
    return type(EntityType)

print(myFunc(Entities.ROCK))
>>>ROCK (where ROCK is an instance of the ROCK class)
```

and if there is a way to do that, is there one, to maybe even initialise the class
eg.:

```
def myFunc(EntityType):
    myObj = EntityType(pos=(0,0))
    return myObj
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What if you just ditch the `auto` and use the classes themselves as the values of `Entities`?  Suppose `Tree`, `Rock`, and `Flower` are the names of your classes:

```
class Entities(Enum):
    TREE = Tree
    ROCK = Rock
    FLOWER = Flower
```

Here `Entities.TREE.value` is the class constructor for `Tree`.

Comment: This won't really help to initialize anything unless all the targets have identical initializers.

Answer (score 2):

Here an example to Kyle Parsons' answer:

```
from enum import Enum
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Animal:
    name: str
    age: int
    type: str = None

@dataclass
class Cat(Animal):
    type: str = 'Cat'

@dataclass
class Dog(Animal):
    type: str = 'Dog'


class AnimalType(Enum):
    DOG = Dog
    CAT = Cat


def get_animal(type: Enum, name: str, age: int):
    return type.value(name, age)

print(get_animal(AnimalType.CAT, 'Peter', 12))
```

Comment: This just emphasizes that all the target types have to have identical constructors.

Answer (score 1):

You can add attributes to an `Enum` object, or you can map an `Enum` using a `dict`. There are other options as well, but these seem simplest.

Let's say you have classes `Tree`, `Rock`, `Flower`, etc, corresponding to the values of the `Enum`:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, height, coords):
        pass

class Rock:
    def __init__(self, coords):
        pass

class Flower:
    def __init__(self, color, iscarnivore, coords):
        pass
```

I've specifically shown an extended version, where each class has a different initializer, and a different set of defaults. If they are all the same, use the existing answers.

Option 1 is to define the enum like this:

```
class Entities(Enum):
    TREE = (Tree, 100, (0, 0))
    ROCK = (Rock, (0, 0))
    FLOWER = (Flower, 'red', True, (0, 0))

    def __new__(cls, t, *args):
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = len(cls.__members__) + 1
        obj.type = t
        obj.defaults = args
        return obj

    def init(self):
        return self.type(*self.defaults)
```

Now, `my_func` is just the `init` method of the enum itself:

```
>>> FLOWER.init() # Calls Flower('red', False, (0, 0))
```

The second option would be to map the `Enum` members to the class:

```
cmap = {
    Entitites.TREE: (Tree, 100, (0, 0)),
    Entitites.ROCK: (Rock, (0, 0)),
    Entitites.FLOWER: (Flower, 'red', True, (0, 0)),
}

def my_func(entity):
    t, *args = cmap[entity]
    return t(*args)
```